# How to Unit Test Vue JS router watch

Tags: vue.js, router, watch

I am looking for inputs to test watch on vue router. I'am using the below code to watch the router and its working

```
watch: {'$route' (to, from) {
    if (to !== from) {
      this.method1()
    }
  }
  }
```

How do we unit test this ? Can anyone please share some sample code on how to unit test watch on router and check if the method was called ? 
I tried the below but it did not work

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
localVue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter({ routes: [{path: '/my-route',
  name: 'my-route',
  fullPath: '/my-route',
  params: {}}] })
const wrapper = mount(myComponent, {store,
  localVue,
  router})
wrapper.setData({ router: {path: '/employee/', fullPath: '/employee/', params: {Id: 1}} });
      expect(actions.method1.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
```

Error:-
AssertionError: expected false to equal true